# How to get just the firmware descriptions without trailing spaces output from the output of command bcdedit /enum firmware?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

The execution of `bcdedit /enum firmware | findstr "description"` results in the output:

```
description             ATA HDD: ADATA SU650                             
description             LinuxMint
description             DisablePROCHOT UEFI
description             rEFInd Boot Manager
```

I use a `for` loop for processing the output:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "fwdes=bcdedit /enum firmware ^| findstr "description""
for /f "usebackq Tokens=1*" %%a in (`%fwdes%`) do echo [%%b]
pause
```

The output is:

```
[ATA HDD: ADATA SU650                             ]
[LinuxMint]
[DisablePROCHOT UEFI]
[rEFInd Boot Manager]
```

How could I remove the additional **trailing spaces** in output after `ATA HDD: ADATA SU650` to become just `[ATA HDD: ADATA SU650]` like on the other lines?

I first thought the whitespaces after `ATA HDD: ADATA SU650` are horizontal tabs but it turned out that they are spaces after redirecting the output into a text file and viewing the text file with a hex editor showing bytes with hexadecimal `20` after the string of the hard disk.

**Fix with this code:**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Sys32=%SystemRoot%\System32
set "fwdes=%Sys32%\bcdedit.exe /enum firmware^| %Sys32%\findstr.exe "description""
for /f "usebackq Tokens=1*" %%a in (`%fwdes%`) do (
    echo %%b | %Sys32%\findstr.exe /c:"SU650" >nul && (
    for /f "Tokens=1-4" %%s in ('echo %%b') do echo [%%s %%t %%u %%v]) || (echo [%%b])
)
pause
```

The output is:

```
[ATA HDD: ADATA SU650]
[LinuxMint]
[DisablePROCHOT UEFI]
[rEFInd Boot Manager]
```

There is perhaps a faster and easier method.

Comment: Are those spaces between `SU650` and `]` supposed to be the tabs that you want removed?

Comment: Would seem odd that the output from bcedit would have a tab in the output.  But you already know that the `FOR /F` command splits up the output from a command into tokens.  So pass the data through another `FOR /F` and use the `DELIMS` option to set the delimiter to a `TAB` only.  By default `FOR /F` uses a space and tab as the delimiters.

Comment: - @SomethingDark Yes.  spaces/ tabs between SU650 and  ]. To become "SU650]"

Comment: - @Squashman How to do it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to post the **actual** output of `bcdedit /enum firmware | findstr "description"` and not assume that `bcdedit` output is known to all. I'd suggest `…do set "line=[%%b]"&set "line=!line:\t=!"&echo/!line!`, where `\t` is an actual tab character.

Comment: -@Magoo I've tried. the result is the same

Comment: The output from your `bcdedit` command, as posted by you, does not display any characters whatsoever after the string SU650, (ignoring the obvious invisible CR and/or LF). If you had pasted the result, as is, directly from the output of the command, which we should all have expected, that should not have happened. So you have either modified the output unnecessarily, or you have invented the problem. The issue is that many of the Manufacturer's strings you are trying to capture are typed into a box which either adds or hides trailing characters, then bcdedit displays data in a tabular format.

Comment: link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18ML7_PtKYCyy5yPWiYP8VXHytMbhAm8J/view?usp=drive_link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution for getting output the firmware descriptions without trailing spaces is:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
(for /F "tokens=1*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\bcdedit.exe /enum FIRMWARE ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /L "description"') do set "Description=%%J" & call :Output) & pause & exit /B
:Output
if "%Description:~-1%" == " " (set "Description=%Description:~0,-1%" & goto Output) else echo [%Description%]& goto :EOF
```

The batch file must be **run as administrator** as otherwise nothing is output because of `bcdedit.exe` requires the elevated privileges of a local administrator for opening the boot configuration data store.

The first command line defined completely the required execution environment which is:

1. Command echo mode turned off.
2. Command extensions enabled as required for this batch file.
3. Delayed variable expansion disabled as not needed and required for processing also correct firmware descriptions with one or more `!` inside.

The second command line is the main code of the batch file on a single line for a minimum of file system accesses during the execution of the batch file.

There is executed first in background by `for /F`:

```
%ComSpec% /c %SystemRoot%\System32\bcdedit.exe /enum FIRMWARE | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /L "description"
```

The redirection operator `|` must be escaped with `^` in the **FOR /F** command line for being interpreted literally by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file. The command process started in background gets passed only the vertical bar character and interprets it for that reason as redirection operator.

The output of `bcdedit.exe` is redirected to `findstr.exe` which filters out all lines not beginning case-sensitive with the string `description`.

That filtered output of `bcdedit.exe` is captured by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file and processed line by line by **FOR** after the started `cmd.exe` closed itself after execution of the two executables.

Each captured line is split up into two substrings. The first one is `description` which is assigned to the specified loop variable `I`. The string after the spaces after `description` is assigned with all its spaces including the trailing spaces to the next loop variable `J` according to the ASCII table.

This string is assigned to the environment variable `Description` before a subroutine with name `Output` is called which processes the description further and finally outputs the description. It is expected by this code that no firmware description contains ever one or more double quotes.

The subroutine compares the last character of the current string value of the environment variable `Description` with a space. If that condition is true, the environment variable `Description` is redefined without the trailing space and the last character check is done once again by continuation of the batch file processing on the same line by using command **GOTO** instead of the not existing next line. The **ELSE** branch of the **IF** condition in the subroutine `Output` is run only if the last character of the current description is not a space character and outputs the trimmed description in square brackets. Then the subroutine is exited with `goto :EOF` and batch file processing continues with processing the next captured line by **FOR /F**.

Once the **FOR /F** loop finished processing all lines, the command **PAUSE** is executed for halting the batch file processing until the user presses a key and next `exit /B` is executed to exit the processing of the batch file without running the commands in the subroutine `Output` once more.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `bcdedit /?`
- `bcdedit /enum /?`
- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also:

- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)